# Volume manager of Windows Server 2008 R2 does not show all iSCSI volumes

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage-area-network, iscsi

We set up a backup server (Windows 2008 r2) for our VMware infrastructure which uses an iSCSI SAN for storage. The backup server has to be connected to the SAN for Veeam to be able to backup virtual machines. The SAN provides 18 targets, all of the same size (1TB).

All initiators (ESX, Windows 2003 r2, Windows 2008 r2) are connecting fine, but the volume manager of Win2k8r2 only shows part of the targets/volumes.

For example: we connect Windows 2008 r2 to all 18 targets, the targets show as "connected" in Microsoft initiator, but volume manager only shows 8 of the targets.

For comparison: the volume manager of Windows 2003 r2 behaves normal and produces one volume for every connected target.

Restarting iSCSI initiator service or rebooting the machine did not help.

[image: iSCSI-Initiator]

[image: Disk management]

[image: No MPIO defined]

[image: No volumes available for MPIO]

Comment: What kind of SAN? Can you post the iSCSI initiator config (screencaps) and screencaps of the disk management panel in Windows?

I assume you tried to rescan disks in disk management?

Comment: Jeremy, thanks for reading my post. I added some screens hoping to illustrate the situation. If you are looking for something more specific let me know. The SAN is based on open-e DSS V6 (latest release).

Comment: I assume you did a rescan disks and that the remaining 8 volumes aren't coming up?

Do you have MPIO enabled (in Windows 2008)? I wonder if MPIO is seeing the volumes as the same even though they are different.

Comment: I did a rescan everytime I disconnected and reconnected the targets. MPIO is not enabled. Or is there any way to configure MPIO outside of MS Initiator that I am missing here?

Comment: See http://i.imgur.com/pkgZu.png. Check to see if MPIO is enabled for any of the targets. Is it?

Comment: I added some more screenshots showing that MPIO is not defined for any of the connected volumes (targets 00 through 07). Targets 08 through 17 are connected but due to the fact that there is no corresponding volume I can not define any MPIO. Btw MPIO is not necessary in this case anyway.

Comment: I am stumped, sorry! I was hoping that there was an MPIO error that was causing Win2k8R2 to "merge" two distinct volumes into one, but clearly that's not it. I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Ok. Thanks anyway for your input! I wasn't aware of the MPIO thing. So I will keep that in mind for fututre installations :-)

Comment: It's not likely to happen, but it is a possibility. Good luck!